# XCode Image dimensions @3

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I have a general question about XCode / IOS. I know that i can upload several images for all IOS devices(original,@2,@3). I coded know a app and 30% of the time i needed for image processing. I want to understand the way, how XCode handles images. 
My Question: Is it enough, when i just add a @3 image? Does XCode scale it down to all devices while building or does the device (iPhone) itself scaling the images down to optimized sizes while running the app?

Does the One-Image-Method cause performance problems on @2 and @1 devices or will IOS reject the app because of missing images for specific devices?

How are you handling this issue?

Answer (score 2):

You have to include @1x, @2x and @3x in an asset catalog. iOS will then select the correct size for the device.
I personally use [Asset Catalog Creator](https://itunes.apple.com/app/asset-catalog-creator-free/id866571115?mt=12) to create all my asset catalogs. It will resize and create all the files for you.

Answer (score 2):

If you only use @3x, Xcode does not scale it down to all device. the device (iPhone) itself does  not scaling the images down to optimized sizes while running the app.

This One-Image-Method cause does performance problems on @2 and @1 devices,you cannot see the picture on @2x or @1x devices.

IOS will most probably reject the app because of missing images for specific devices.

If your app is developed for all device , You have to include @1x, @2x and @3x. I use A Xcode plugin Named [RTImageAssets](https://github.com/rickytan/RTImageAssets) to create all my asset catalogs.